# how to return the whole element value length that contains specific letters using String method in dart

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart

here i have String list and String variable which cotwins the wanted letters

```
List myBooks ['hello world' , 'hello dart', 'hello flutter'] ;

String isBook = 'flutter' // here i target the hello flutter element
```

here i have Text Widget and String Method

```
Text(getBook(isBook ))

String getBook(String isBook ){
 return // here i need to return the whole length of element that contains 'flutter'
so i need to get 'hello flutter'
}
```

How to handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`List.firstWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) to find element and [`.contains()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/contains.html) to check value;

```dart
String getBook(String isBook) {
  List myBooks = ['hello world', 'hello dart', 'hello flutter'];

  return myBooks.firstWhere((b) => b.contains(isBook));
}

void main() {
  String isBook = 'flutter';
  
  print(getBook(isBook)); // hello flutter
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , very useful answer , that's what i want as well